# PHP script not able to connect to MS SQL database in webmatrix

Tags: php, sql-server, webmatrix

I am using webmatrix and trying to connect to a local database in that which is SQL database . I have IIS and SQL Server  installed on the computer . The database was created in webmatrix only .
Initially the error display was not on , I managed to do that by manipulating the php.ini file . After that I tried this script which is giving the following result .

```
<?php
    if (function_exists('mssql_connect')){
echo "Okay, fn is there<br>------------------<br>";
} else {
echo "Hmmm .. fn is not even there<br>------------------<br>";
}

if(extension_loaded("mssql")) {
echo "MSSQL is Loaded<br>";
}
else {
echo "MSSQL not loaded<br>";
}

if(extension_loaded("msql")) {
echo "MSQL is Loaded<br>";
}
else {
echo "MSQL not loaded<br>";
}
echo '<br><br>';

$ext = get_loaded_extensions();
if(in_array('mssql', $ext))
echo 'u have mssql installed<br><br>';
else
echo 'u do NOT have mssql installed<br><br>';

?>
```

The result is :

### Hmmm .. fn is not even there

MSSQL not loaded
MSQL not loaded

u do NOT have mssql installed

This is the command I was using to connect to mssql database

```
<?php
$con=mssql_connect('.\SQLEXPRESS','Shops_localdbU','thePass');
if($con) {
echo "success";
}
?>
```

and output was:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

May be the functions are not installed on your server. If you have access to install them, then you can do that. If not, you cannot use these functions.

If you do have permission to modify the PHP configuration, start here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php

Comment: how to do that on windows ?

Comment: here is the guide for windows http://www.sqlserverclub.com/essentialguides/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-step-by-step-guide.aspx

Comment: Why you are not using mysql

Comment: The client needs the database to be in MS SQL server so I'll be creating it in that format only so that its easy to transfer it later.

Comment: So there are many tutorials available to install on windows too. just google it